# Choose between Phone number and AlphaNumeric Sender Id when send SMS in Messaging Service

Tags: twilio

I added a phone number and an Alphanumeric Sender Id to a Messaging Service.
And my app has a logic to choose between sending by a Phone number or AlphaSenderId.

Could you please provide me API in Messaging Service to have the ability to choose between the Phone number and AlphaSenderId when sending an SMS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The messaging service will pick the sender automatically based on the country you send the message to. From the [doc](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/services#alpha-sender):

> If you add an Alpha Sender to your Twilio Messaging Service, Twilio will select the Alphanumeric Sender ID automatically when you send a message to a supported country, unless you also have a short code number in that same country.

I.e. you cannot influence this manually when you send a message via such an API call:

```js
client.messages
  .create({
     body: 'Revenge of the Sith was clearly the best of the prequel trilogy.',
     from: 'MG9752274e9e519418a7406176694466fa',
     to: '+441632960675'
   })
  .then(message => console.log(message.sid));
```

But you could do something like this:

```js
const useMS = false;
client.messages
  .create({
     body: 'Revenge of the Sith was clearly the best of the prequel trilogy.',
     from: useMS ? 'MG9752274e9e519418a7406176694466fa' :  '+441632960670',
     to: '+441632960675'
   })
  .then(message => console.log(message.sid));
```

or use the `messagingServiceSid` property in combination with `from`:

```js
client.messages
  .create({
    from: useAlpha ? 'AlphaSenderID' :  '+440000000',
    messagingServiceSid: "MGxxxxxx",
    body: 'Revenge of the Sith was clearly the best of the prequel trilogy.',
    to: '+441632960675'
   })
  .then(message => console.log(message.sid));
```